# Javascript: Create two Elements and change their class by onclick on them

Tags: javascript, onclick, getelementbyid, element

I want to click on a div and create with javascript two elements then i want to click to one of the new elements and change the class of the other. Most of it works until the point i want to change the class by calling a function called divide() buttontranslate.onclick=divide();

here i have this fiddle that doesn't really work but i am sure you can figure out what i am talking about. Am i doing this whole thing wrong? OR i just miss a small detail?
http://jsfiddle.net/alexnode/UD6fk/16/

```
function myfunction(){


var tr1 = document.createElement("tr1");
var buttontranslate = document.createElement("buttontranslate");
tr1.className="trpanel";
tr1.id="trpanela";
buttontranslate.style.cssText='width:5%;height:100%;right:0px;top:0px;background:black;color:white;position:fixed;z-index:2300;cursor:pointer;'
buttontranslate.innerHTML="translate"
//buttontranslate.onclick=divide(); here is the problem


tr1.innerHTML = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,";

document.body.appendChild(tr1);
document.body.appendChild(buttontranslate);



}
function divide(){ 
document.getElementById("trpanela").className = "centerpanel";
 }
```

Edit : This is the corrected JSfiddle with instructions by Paul S http://jsfiddle.net/alexnode/UD6fk/35/

Comment: What is a `<tr1>`? What is a `<buttontranslate>`? You are working in XML and not HTML?

Comment: no i just added these names so i can remember them.

Comment: @alexnode: You shouldn't make up elements.

Comment: should I only use nav and div etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just make up new elements; it wouldn't be valid *HTML*.
When setting an *onclick* property, you need to pass a *function*, not invoke that function.

See the changes I made to your fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/UD6fk/17/)

```
function myfunction() {
    var tr1 = document.createElement("span"), // real elements
        buttontranslate = document.createElement("button");
    tr1.className = "trpanel";
    tr1.id = "trpanela";
    buttontranslate.className = "translate";
    buttontranslate.innerHTML = "translate"
    buttontranslate.onclick = divide; // no () because we dont want to invoke
    tr1.innerHTML = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, etc...";

    document.body.appendChild(tr1);
    document.body.appendChild(buttontranslate);
}

myfunction(); // invoke on page load

function divide() {
    document.getElementById("trpanela").className = "centerpanel";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I am not sure that I understand very well the order we have to invoke the divide. The problem is that all these happen after I click a button and then I run a script to create the elements just once. So i can't load the myfunction on page load. But i believe i am heading in the right direction with your help. I was confused with the elements i thought they are like classes. Really helpful post.